# extracting data from file inbwetween key words

Tags: python

im trying to write a program that extracts data from a text file in between two key words and puts the data into a list of tuples, with the date as a string and the data as an int. I cannot use for loops only while loops

begin step data

2010-01-01,1000

2010-01-02,2000

end step data

needs extracted into this format [('2001-01-01', 12776), ('2001-01-02', 15128)]

I have written this program:

```
mylist = []

line = open(filename).read()


start = '<begin step data>'
end = '<end step data>'


startpos = line.find(start) + len(start)
endpos = line.find(end, startpos)
data = line[startpos:endpos].strip("")

mylist.append(data.split())
```

but this puts it in a wrong format: [['2001-01-01,12776', '2001-01-02,15128']]

I think i may have the wrong aproach to this and should be using readlines instead of read

Comment: Wait why would anyone want to program in python without using for loops ?

Comment: I don't know but at the course, im studying they always make us do stuff with out for loops for some reason.

Comment: Alrite.. gonna go for an answer anyway, but I don't think you should follow a course on programation that doesn't even try to make you use a tool appropriate for what it wants you to learn. 

When learning beginner programmation, for loops are often forbidden because they are too easy and end up being overused, but current CPython is optimized for those..

Comment: its an introductory python course at uni, which apparently has the highest fail rate of any course. I am not studying to be a computer scientist, I study GIS and i was recommended this as a complementary course since ArcMap runs on python but it is quite difficult with no programming experience.

Comment: Currently can't post my answer for "unproperly formatted code", gonna get to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a readlines, but you would end up having to emulate for loops behavior to go through each lines and stuff, which you don't want.

Your problem, however, lies somewhere else : **You can't simply strip character lists from a spliting char and expect it to get you the good format.**

If you get something like `[['2001-01-01,12776', '2001-01-02,15128']]`, and since you don't appear to be seeking perfection, you can simply take what you already have and :

1. Iterate through each string in array[0].
2. Split those strings in two set of data.
3. Cast the second data into number.

Using for loops, which you can then convert..

```
desired_format = [] # Initialize empty result array.
for element in curr_result[0]: 
    element = element.split(',') # Separate values separated by comas.

    # Finally add seeken results as tuples.
    desired_format.append(
        (
            element[0],
            int(element[1]) # Cast second element as integer. 
        )
    )
```

(Where the middle parenthesis are initalizing a tuple.)

Note that as mentionned, this is a quick and dirty fix for current issue, but there would be much better ways to do it, which you can probably dig out later.

But you won't be stopped here in your bonus course. ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression with the `re` module (deeper explanation of the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/eGA7fO/2)):

```
# Find the (date, data) pairs
matches = re.findall('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}),(\d+)', text)
# Convert the data to an integer
matches = map(lambda m: (m[0], int(m[1])), matches)
```

If you wanted to, you could even cut it down to one line by using the `re.findall` call as the second argument to `map`.

Comment: this worked perfectly but is hard to read for a beginner, guess I will read up on regex

Comment: @JayDilla: Regex is a bit hard to get into, but once your understand the basics, you can build on it and do some powerful stuff. Best of luck!

Comment: il just add that this method works in python 2 but you have to convert it to a list in python 3. This is because apparently  range gives a list in python 2, but gives a range object in python 3. I just added print(list(matches)) to crorrect this.

Comment: @JayDilla: That's exactly right. I'm not sure if you're allowed to do it, but you may want to use a list comprehension: `[(date, int(data)) for date, data in matches]`.